# Can I change my sect?

Tags: vishnu, madhwa

I am from shaiva sect but i like and love Krishna . And my bramhopadesham in madhwa style can I change to madhwa does madhwa community accept me ?

Comment: I think you are free to accept any sect but also don't completely forsake your Kula Devatha (i think Shiva here).

Comment: Belonging to a sect requires getting initiated by one of that  sect's Gurus. And which u can always do  if u and ur elders are ok with it. What is the point of asking us?

Comment: @Rickross i am asking that can I change my sect to madhwa my elders are ok with it thank you for your answer both of you

Comment: Sect is not by birth alone. You can choose where you feel more affinity.

Comment: Is it really necessary to carry a label or to belong to a certain sect? ... Why not be free from these labels , that im a shaiva, im a shakta or vaishnava etc. etc. and just pray to whichever God you like the most?

Comment: Yes u are right. Although to practice the religion one should according to the rules belong to a sect but too much indulgence in sectarianism is directly against spirituality and so it's a bad practice. @TheCrimsonUniverse